# How modify styles of an element by check an input radio

Tags: input, checkbox

`let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');

```
      inputs.forEach( el => {
        el.addEventListener("change", (e)=>{
          let targ = e.target;
          let toChange = document.querySelector('.select-answer');
          console.log(el)
          if(targ == el && el.getAttribute('aria-selected') == 'false' && el.getAttribute('data-id')){
            console.log(targ);
            toChange.classList.toggle('false');
          }
        },false);`
```

[I selected second input but the styles was aplied just for first element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sy80C.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! When you write your question, there is an option available to add the JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet (you can use Ctrl-M hotkey for that). You'd better add the full snippet, or at least some HTML/CSS code you're using, your screenshot makes little sense since there is no HTML/CSS source for it.